# Is there any plan to standardize the Quintus/SICStus style module system in ISO Prolog?

Tags: module, prolog, iso-prolog

The ISO standard for Prolog modules (ISO/IEC 13211-2) was never widely adopted, instead it seems almost all Prolog systems in wide use today use a Quintus/SICStus style module system (SWI, SICStus, ...) and basically all new Prolog systems being developed are also adopting it (Scryer, Trealla, ...).

So, is there any plan to standardize the Quintus/SICStus style module system (or a subset of it) in ISO Prolog?

Comment: I suggest you read https://logtalk.org/rationale.html

Comment: This kind of question is not suitable for SO. Please reread https://stackoverflow.com/tour. You are implying here so many incorrect things, that just answering these takes time.

Comment: @false Makes sense. I thought about emailing you about this, because you work on ISO as far as I know, but I thought that asking in a public place would be better. What I explained here was prefixed with "As far as I know" exactly because I don't know much about this topic, I just wanted to give some context as to why I would ask something like that.

Comment: In your very first sentence, there is no prefix at all, and as it stands it is false on so many levels. Here on SO you really need to stick to factual questions and not opinion-related hearsay.

Comment: I simplified the entire question to be less subjective and smaller in scope, I hope that is better. I'm still not sure if this question is adequate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Does an explanation of the ISO standard for Prolog modules exist outside the actual ISO document ISO/IEC 13211-2?